# java.lang.RuntimeException: WakeLock under-locked wake:com.google.firebase.messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using **FCM** (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to send data messages
to the clients via `topics`.

I recently see rare occurrences of this bug / crash.

**Full log:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: WakeLock under-locked wake:com.google.firebase.messaging
   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:1619)
   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:1589)
   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock$1.run(PowerManager.java:1484)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

SideNode: It only seems to occur on **HUAWAI** devices with **Android 8**.

**Client:** 
The client will receive those data messages, entangle the data part,
do a fast API call and finally show a notification to the user.

This works usually like a charm, but now I see those weird crashes.

Does know anybody what is happening here?

**Additionally**
In android source code I could see that this might be thrown, 
if a wake lock is being released, although there is no lock anymore.
That is why it is called *under-locked* I suppose.

[Source Code PowerManager Line:2222](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java#2222)

Comment: had it with Android 7 / HUAWEI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Firebase changelog Cloud Messaging versions 20.1.4 and 20.1.5 were causing this bug, you need to upgrade to 20.1.6 :

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v20-1-5

Comment: Just wanted to point to my filed issue, which has been closed! fyi: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1484

Comment: I see the same issue on cloud messaging 20.2.0

Comment: It's still occuring with bom 31.1.1